# SQL Schema - Default of 1:Many

Tags: mysql, schema, entity-relationship

How can I specify the default value of a 1:Many relationship ... for example take a user that has 5 phone numbers ... I need to record the "preferred" phone number. Should I use an attribute on the phone_number record to indicate the preferred one - or have a attribute of the user record (`preferred_phone_number` for example) that is the primary key from the phone_numbers table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `User.preferred_phone`: you have zero or one preferred numbers per user.
2. `Phone.is_preferred`: you may have any amount of preferred numbers per user, without a way to choose the 'most preferred', and even 'preferred numbers' that no user relates to.

So I'd clearly stick with #1.

Comment: and User.preferred_phone would be the primary key from the phone_numbers table ? ie a foreign key (sorry for the over-clarification - just getting my head into this stuff !)

Comment: Yes, nullable `User.preferred_phone` is a foreign key referencing `Phone.id`. This way you always point to a valid phone (or to no phone). There's a downside: you potentially may point to a phone that is not associated with this user. An `on update` trigger may check this.